# iPhone App no longer has write permissions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I have an app that needs to be able to write to the /var/mobile/Applications/.../Documents directory.  This was working fine, but for some reason now when I run my code NSFileManager createFileAtPath returns NO every time.  I have no idea why this is occurring, does anyone else?  I am wondering if I somehow changed some target settings by accident...

Any help is appreciated,

Robin

Note: this occurs for any data I attempt to write (NSString, NSDictionary, etc)

```
NSDictionary *dataToWrite = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1234", @"id", @"hfjk", @"password",nil]; 
NSArray *arrayPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(

                                                          NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDirectory = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
filePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/sample-file-name"];
NSFileManager *fileMgr;
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[archiver encodeObject:dataToWrite forKey:@"any-key"];
[archiver finishEncoding];

BOOL status = [fileMgr createFileAtPath:path contents:data attributes:nil];
if (status)
    NSLog(@"Created file at path: %@",path);
else
    NSLog(@"Failed to create file at path: %@",path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Insteaf of writing,

```
filePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/sample-file-name"];
```

Please check with this

```
filePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample-file-name"];
```

Please check [NSFileManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)